# What is the reason for pink discoloration in pink disease or acrodynia

Tags: dermatology, mercury

Pink disease or acrodynia is a reaction to large doses of amalgam.
It is an uncommon mercurial toxicity reaction in which skin is involved.

According to[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrodynia):

> Acrodynia is a condition of pain and dusky pink discoloration in the hands and feet most often seen in children chronically exposed to heavy metals, especially mercury.

My question is what is the reason behind the pinkish discoloration?
I searched on google, however didn't find any Pathophysiology behind the discoloration.

[image]

[ImageReference](https://medcaretips.com/acrodynia/)